# Database-save results in psycopg2 error **"A field with precision 4, scale 3 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1*"***

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm stuck with an issue in psycopg2 regarding a numeric type field that results in an exception and I can't figure out the cause.

I'm calculating some values that are passed into a class init method among which there is a decimal value field that is a NUMERIC(4,3) in the Postgres database and a Column(Float(3)) in the sqlalchemy model class used in the ORM. If I save it with a simple INSERT statement using ROUND() function (say the value is 0.034) it works fine, but if I do the rounding in the Python code with round() function and try to save it, it throws an error: "A field with precision 4, scale 3 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1" Which is strange since the value is by all means matches the requirements. I use Flask for the API and sqlalchemy for ORM, but not Flask-sqlalchemy.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_cal_table_name(
    id                        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      [...other columns...]
    first_second_ratio        NUMERIC(4,3) NOT NULL,
    second_double_fault_ratio NUMERIC(4,3) NOT NULL,
      [...other columns...]
);
```

Data class:

```
@dataclass
class TableName(TableBase):
    __tablename__ = 't_cal_table_name'
    __table_args__ = ([constraints_and_stuff])

    [...other columns...]
    first_second_ratio = Column(Float(3), nullable=False)
    second_double_fault_ratio = Column(Float(3), nullable=False)
    [....other columns...]
```

I do the rounding before saving like this:

```
    first_second_ratio = round(first_serve_sum / second_serve_sum, 3)
    second_double_fault_ratio = round(second_serve_sum / double_fault_sum, 3)
```

Comment: Read [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL): *The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. *. Best best is you are seeing: `select 12.34::numeric(4,3); ERROR:  numeric field overflow DETAIL:  A field with precision 4, scale 3 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.`

Comment: Why use `Float()` when there is [Numeric](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric) available?

Comment: Thank you for both comments. 1. I've read the docs, I know how numeric scale and precision work. 0.034 fits in NUMERIC(4,3) in my understanding. 2. Numeric caused me issues before, and Float solved it back then.

Comment: `0.034` and `select select .123456::float::numeric(4,3);; 0.123` will work. That is not the issue,`numeric(4,3)` only allows you 1 digit to left of decimal place. Check the Postgres logs to see what is actually hitting the database when the error occurs. I'm betting the value has at least 2 digits to left of decimal place. If not then it one of those imprecise float values that don't convert to numeric properly.